# Flutter Completer

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I'm not familiar with Completer but I would like to know if it is possible to concatenate a series of Future to handle a data request.

I have to send a List of bytes (data, example; [62,73,65,67,75,13,10]) through a socket connection byte-by-byte and cannot send the next byte before I get an answer from the host. The host will answer with the same character sent (echo) so, once I receive the answer from the host I can then send next char. Working with Future.delayed is too complicate, the delays varies depending on network latency too much, so I was thinking to create Futures with Completer. Don't know how to handle this with Completer but will appreciate any help, suggestion, thanks in advance for any kind of support. Below is part of my code ...

```
List<Completer<bool>> bytes = [];

@override
void send(dynamic data) async {
  bytes.clear();
  byteCount = 0;
  for (var byte in data) {
    bytes.add(Completer<bool>());
    byteSent = [byte].toString();
    try {
      _udpSocket.send([byte], ipAddress!, portNumber!);
      await bytes[byteCount].future;
      byteCount++;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}

@override
Future<bool> connect() async {
  ...
  reader.listen((data) {
    byteReceived = data.toString();
    if (byteReceived == byteSent) {
      bytes[byteCount].complete(true);
    }
    buffer.addAll(data);
    controller.sink.add(buffer.sublist(0, buffer.length - 2));
  });
}
```

S.

Comment: use https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamQueue-class.html or https://api.dartlang.org/stable/dart-async/StreamIterator-class.html, ask Google for some code snippets if not sure

Comment: this is a sample using `StreamIterator`: `foo() async {
final cmd = 'my command\n';

final s = await Socket.connect('localhost', 65432);
final resp = StreamIterator(s);
print('** start');
await Future.forEach(cmd.codeUnits, (cu) async {
print('sending $cu |${String.fromCharCode(cu)}|');
s.add([cu]);
final b = await resp.moveNext();
final data = resp.current;
print('received $b $data |${String.fromCharCodes(data)}|');
});
print('** end');
}` - it uses TCP socket, in your case you should use your `_udpSocket` - no need for calling `listen`, playing with multiple `Completer`s etc

Comment: and of course you can use "normal" `for` loop: `foo() async {
final cmd = 'my command\n';

final s = await Socket.connect('localhost', 65432);
final resp = StreamIterator(s);
print('** start');
for (final cu in cmd.codeUnits) {
print('sending $cu |${String.fromCharCode(cu)}|');
s.add([cu]);
final b = await resp.moveNext();
final data = resp.current;
print('received $b $data |${String.fromCharCodes(data)}|');
}
print('** end');
}`

Comment: Thanks @pskink your code works fine if you only need to send data to the host, the issue is that I must be able to listen the data coming from the host. So whenever the host send an answer, the StreamIterator is then queuing the data and what you sent after, never match the StreamIterator resp.current ...

Comment: so use `StreamQueue`  - it can return the rest of the stream - https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamQueue/rest.html

Comment: btw it can be even easier to use [ChunkedStreamReader](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/ChunkedStreamReader-class.html) - check it out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can modify your code like this to be sure data has been sent sequentially:

```dart
Completer<bool> _sendCompleter = Completer<bool>();

@override
void send(List<int> data) async {
  for (var byte in data) {
    byteSent = byte.toString();
    try {
      _udpSocket.send([byte], ipAddress!, portNumber!);

      await _sendCompleter.future;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}

@override
Future<bool> connect() async {
  reader.listen((data) {
    byteReceived = data.toString();
    buffer.addAll(data);
 
    controller.sink.add(buffer.sublist(0, buffer.length - 2));

    _sendCompleter.complete(true);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi @hamed, your answer was very close. I edited my code with the solution that worked fine for me. Thanks for your help and support.